# Out of Memory Exception while retrieving large data using web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am facing Out of Memory Exception while retrieving large data using web services. it works fine for small amount of data. now in production using large amount of data more than 3 to 4 GB, facing Out of Memory Exception. here we use xml serialization and deserialization.

any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Not sure exactly what help you are looking for but I suspect you aren't going to like the answers. 1. Send smaller chunks of data, 2. Move to a 64-bit solution and make sure there's enough available memory, ideally physical, in your system.

Comment: Available memory has very little to do with it.  What is happening is the runtime is trying to allocate large blocks of contiguous memory, which can't be found.

Comment: there is 6 GB of memory is available. and recently increased virtual directory memory usage to maximum.

Comment: @Pradeep: Complain to MS, they only allocate 1GB of physical memory per web app.

Comment: i have read in some article that there is chance to increase that size, is it not please tell me.

Comment: @Pradeep: The only way is to run a web farm IIRC. You will need to refactor youre code or compress the XML.

Comment: @Chris Marisic: I can't recall, will have to try fish it out of my browser history at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent a while looking into out of memory issues while processing XML. Here are a few hints and suggestions:

1) Maximum process size on the 32bit machine can be 2GB and if a startup switch specific, 3GB. So it is a must that 64bit kit is used.

2) Run perfmon.exe to collect samples and see how big memory usage gets for your process before crashing. If you run on 64bit, make sure it is compiled for 64bit otherwise it will run it using WOW and in 32 bit mode.

3) In .NET 1.1, loading a 100MB XML would take 600-800MB of space if processed using `XmlDocument`. In .NET 2.0 and later it is 3-4 times but still considerable. Avoid `XmlDocument` when you can.

4) **This I think can be your problem: avoid recreating your serializers**. .NET actually spits out code and compiles them into assemblies which cannot be unloaded as you know and causes **memory leak** which is known issue and happens with XSLT transform as well. Always cache your serializers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I kind of alluded to in the comment is the fact that the runtime cannot allocate a big enough contiguous block of memory.

Eric Lippert has a great blog post on this problem: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx

Comment: IIS (on 64-bit) limits a wep app to 1GB physical and 5GB virtual memory, totalling 6GB. Sorry, I do not have a link to where I read that.

Comment: Can anyone substantiate leppie's statements? Those seem to be very arbitrary limits.

Comment: @Chris Marisic: Trying to find it :(  It was kinda specific, it failed while trying to allocate a block of 256MB memory during compression, on a WCF service returning rather large datasets. I will go through my emails and browser history to see if I can find it. As a last resort, I could always recreate the exception, and try search for the same message I got.